# How to free linked list in the Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, list, linked-list

I have a structure like this

```
struct list
{
    struct list *next;

    int temp;
};
```

I use the following method to free

…. …. ….

```
// free linked list
struct list *head_list = NULL;
struct list *current_list = NULL;
struct list *prev_list = NULL;

current_list = head_list;
while (current_file_info_arr != NULL)
{
    prev_list = current_list;
    current_list = current_list->next;
    free(prev_list);
}
```

I get the warning

```
Memory error
Use of memory after it is freed
```

Is there any good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to replace

```
while (current_file_info_arr != NULL)
```

with

```
while (current_list != NULL)
```

But that's assuming you actually have a list in place - allocated/constructed previously - and `head_list` points to beginning of it. If `head_list` is `NULL`, like in your snippet:

```
struct list *head_list = NULL;
```

then the `Memory error` is not a surprise. You are trying to free `NULL`, which is an error, indeed.